# CSS styling for HTML elements in Twig

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

I have a form with fields that looks like this (in plain HTML):

```
<div class = form-group>
<label class="title" for="sign-in">Email Address <span>*</span></label>
<input type="email" class="form-control app-form-control mytext-input" id="sign-in">
</div>
```

In my css file, i have a style that is applied directly to the `span` tag. This style changes the color of the `*` in the tag. 
My question is: How do i represent this on Twig? What is the right syntax? I can't use the `attr` property since the style is applied directly to the HTML element.

Also my `input` element has multiple classes attached to it. What is the right syntax for this? Do i separate them with a comma like this:

```
   {{ from_widget (form.email,{
       'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'app-form-control', 'mytext-input'}
   })  }}
```

OR just place them in the same set of quotes like this:

```
   {{ from_widget (form.email,{
       'attr': {'class': 'form-control app-form-control mytext-input'}
   })  }}
```

**UPDATE:**
*How do i represent this on twig?*
The CSS below is applied directly to the span tag like this (i've included a div tag above):

```
.form-group span {
  color: red;
 }
```

if i had just `.form-group{color: red}` in my CSS i would've simply passed the class name via the `attr` property on the form element in twig. So i'm asking how i would represent the CSS above on Twig.

Comment: Please add the relevant CSS rules in your question. I don't understand this question: *How do i represent this on Twig?* Can you please rephrase it? The first syntax of `'class':` seems to be invalid, the second one should be OK. Have you tested it?

Comment: @A.L  I have updated the question.

Comment: If I understand correctly and you want to add asterisks on required fields, you will find a solution in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#adding-a-required-asterisk-to-field-labels

Comment: Did the documentation helped you? Did it solved your problem?